# A Straigth line appeared when I wanted to draw a curve using plot in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

What I want to plot is the intersection curve of two cylinders as in the figure below, but what appears is a straight line. For simplicity, only post the basic code using to draw the curve.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{border=10pt}[standalone]

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%

  math3d/.style={%%

                                       x={(-0.353cm,-0.353cm)},
                                       z={(0cm,1cm)},
                                       y={(1cm,0cm)},

  }%%


   }%

 \begin{tikzpicture}[math3d]

     \draw node[left] at (0,0,0) {$O$} coordinate (O);

     \draw[->](0,0,0)--(4,0,0);
     \draw node[below left] at (4,0,0) {$X$};

     \draw[->](0,0,0)--(0,5,0);
     \draw node[below right] at (0,5,0) {$Y$};

     \draw[->](0,0,0)--(0,0,5);
     \draw node[below right] at (0,0,5) {$Z$};

     %  curve as intersection of two cylinders
         \draw[variable=\t,samples=30,domain=0:0.5*pi,smooth] 
      plot ({2*cos(deg(\t))}, {2*sin(deg(\t))},{2*sin(deg(\t))}); %  

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is because of the projection you are choosing. If you were to choose different `x`, `y` and `z` vectors, you will see some curvature. In more detail, the 3d vector you plot is of the form `(a,b,b)` and `x` is proportional to `y+z`. so you obtain a straight line.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Wow! Thanks a lot ! I changed the x vector and it worked well !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose an unfortunate projection, for which the curve looks like a line. The curve is given by

```
\draw[variable=\t,samples=30,domain=0:0.5*pi,smooth] 
  plot ({2*cos(deg(\t))}, {2*sin(deg(\t))},{2*sin(deg(\t))});
```

so it has the `y` and `z` components equal. Your choice for `x` is however such that `x` is proportional to `y+z`, so that you get a line. In order to install another projection, you can load the `perspective` library. The following animation shows that the projection of the curve may look like a line for some view angles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {100,105,...,130,125,120,...,105}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-3,-3) rectangle (6,6);
 \begin{scope}[3d view={\X }{20+15*sin((\X-100)*6)}]
     \draw node[left] at (0,0,0) {$O$} coordinate (O);
     \draw[->](0,0,0)--(4,0,0);
     \draw node[below left] at (4,0,0) {$X$};
     \draw[->](0,0,0)--(0,5,0);
     \draw node[below right] at (0,5,0) {$Y$};
     \draw[->](0,0,0)--(0,0,5);
     \draw node[below right] at (0,0,5) {$Z$};

     %  curve as intersection of two cylinders
     \draw[dashed] (2,0,0) -- (2,0,4) -- (0,0,4) -- (0,2,4)
      -- (0,2,2) -- (0,4,2) -- (0,4,0) -- (2,4,0) -- cycle
      plot[variable=\t,samples=30,domain=0:0.5*pi,smooth]
       ({2*sin(deg(\t))},4,{2*cos(deg(\t))});
     \draw 
      plot[variable=\t,samples=30,domain=0:0.5*pi,smooth]
       ({2*cos(deg(\t))}, {2*sin(deg(\t))},{2*sin(deg(\t))});
     \draw  plot[variable=\t,samples=30,domain=0:0.5*pi,smooth]
       ({2*cos(deg(\t))}, 0,{2*sin(deg(\t))}) -- 
      (0,2,2) -- (0,2,0)
       plot[variable=\t,samples=30,domain=0.5*pi:0,smooth]
       ({2*cos(deg(\t))},{2*sin(deg(\t))},0); 
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer! Now I see more clearly how the 3d view setup works!